# List doesn't get populated in p:dataTable on click of p:menuitem

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using a PanelMenu  and a datatable from primefaces .
Required is that when a user clicks on the menuitem corresponding data should be populated in the data.

My POC: 
I am able to get the menuitem clicked in Managed bean.

Problem:

It does come to the desired method but the datatable is not populated with desired set of result.
Below is the piece of code.

```
 @ManagedBean(name="msgTpye")
@SessionScoped
public class MsgType implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3167238749130750720L;
    /**
     * 
     */

    private String msgdesription="";
    private String msgtag="";
    private String msgVal="";


    private List<MsgType> msgValList;

    public MsgType(){

    }
    public MsgType (String msgdesription,String msgtag,String msgVal ){
        this.msgdesription=msgdesription;
        this.msgtag=msgtag;
        this.msgVal=msgVal;
    }


    public List<MsgType>  getMsgTypeList(ActionEvent event){
      String msgType = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("msgTypeParam");
        System.out.println("sss"+msgType);

        List<MsgType> msgValList = new ArrayList<MsgType>();
if("FREETEXT".equals(msgType)){

            msgValList.add(new MsgType("    ","{1100}", "30T N"));
            msgValList.add(new MsgType(""," {1110}","   10111353FT01"));
            msgValList.add(new MsgType(""," {1120}" ,"20121011G1QX370C00004810111353FT01"));
            msgValList.add(new MsgType(""," {1500}","   30ABCDEFGHP" ));
            msgValList.add(new MsgType("","{1510}   ","1000"));
            msgValList.add(new MsgType("","{1520}","    20121011J1Q504AC000001"));
            msgValList.add(new MsgType(""," {2000}","   000000000[AMOUNT]"));
            msgValList.add(new MsgType("","{3100}", "101003317FST NATL BK KS*"));
            msgValList.add(new MsgType("","{3320}","    [REFERENCE]*"));
            msgValList.add(new MsgType("","{3400}"  ,"101102315MARSHALL & ILSLEY*"));
            msgValList.add(new MsgType("","{3600}","    CTR"));
            msgValList.add(new MsgType("","{4100}", "D987543*RIVA BANK*10000 COLLEGE BLVD., STE. 260*OVERLAND OFAC PARK, KS 66210-1400*"));
            msgValList.add(new MsgType("","{4200}","    D101004028651*KOESTEN, HIRSCHMANN & CRABTREE,*INC.*FLEXIBLE BENEFIT PLAN*"));
            msgValList.add(new MsgType("","{5000}", "D077755*KOESTEN HIRSCHMANN & CRABTREE, INC.*10000 COLLEGE BLVD., STE. 260*OVERLAND OFAC PARK, KS 66210-1400*$"));
            msgValList.add(new MsgType("Receiver FI Information ","{6100}"  ,"D987543*[NAME]*10000 COLLEGE BLVD., STE. 260*OVERLAND OFAC PARK, KS 66210-1400*"));



        }else {

            msgValList.add(new MsgType("No Data ", "No data", "No Data"));
    }





        return msgValList;
}
}
```

My xhtml page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="default.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="cssLayout.css" />
</h:head>
<h:body>

<br/>
    <h:form style="width:100%;position:absolute;left:5%;top:22%;border:none">
 <p:panelMenu style="width:100%;align:left">
  <p:submenu label="#{msg.FREETEXT}" >
         <p:menuitem value="#{msg.FREETEXT}" actionListener="#{msgTpye.getMsgTypeList}"   icon="ui-icon-document" >
           <f:attribute name="msgTypeParam" value="FREETEXT" />
                    </p:menuitem>
         </p:submenu>
 </p:panelMenu>
  <p:dataTable id="dataTbl" var="value" value="#{msgTpye.msgValList}"  style="width:100%; align:center;">

 <p:column headerText="#{msg.Tag}">
        <h:outputText value="#{value.msgtag}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="#{msg.Description}">
        <h:outputText value="#{value.msgdesription}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="#{msg.Values}">
         <h:outputText value="#{value.msgVal}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="#{msg.Editable}"></p:column>

</p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your posted code you do not change the value of `List<MsgType> msgValList` but only the value of some local List inside your ActionListener with the same name.

Also, ActionListener-methods should be of type `String` or `void`.

If neccessary update/rerender your datatable after the AJAX call to see the changes done by the ActionListener.

Btw, the name of your ActionListener method suggestt that it is a getter Method. This is not really a problem, but you should use a more appropriate name.

Comment: :I did changed the action listener method to void and started using the list declared at class level
wanted to how to go ahead with AJAX. It will be of great help if you guide me. I am new to JSF.

Comment: I am not sure about the question in your comment. To update the datatable after your AJAX call just add `update="dataTbl"` onto your menuitem

Comment: Can you plz let me know more on how to make AJAX call. In my menuitem there are mulitiple item so do I have to add update for all.

Comment: You are already doing it. When clicking an menuitem the actionListener method is invoked via AJAX